# How can I take every Kth number of a list and measure against the prior nth numbers of the same list?

Tags: python, statistics, counting

I want to take ***every 10th number*** in a list and compare it to the last 9 numbers from the 10th number of the same list and check if any of the last 9 prior numbers fall within +100/-100 range of the 10th number.

So If I have a list with, say 10,000 numbers;

```
large_list = [4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 4332, 4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032, 4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 3342, 3356, 3245, 2356, 4156, 4300, .....]
```

In this instance, every 10th number is 4032 & 4300 and so I want to check if any of the last 9 numbers from 4032 fall within 3932 & 4132, and then check if any of the last 9 prior numbers from 4300 fall within 4200 and 4400, so on and so forth.

Comment: So, since 4504 is the first number, you want to check if 4504 falls between 3932 and 4132?

Comment: Please post your code and clearly show the problem you have with it.  You should be able to make a good attack at a problem you can describe this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the built-in `any()` function to see if any of the last 10 satisfy the condition.

```py
large_list = [4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 4332, 
              4656, 3045, 1056, 4556, 4032, 
              4504, 4405, 4302, 4706, 3342, 
              3356, 3245, 2356, 4156, 4300]

within_range = []
step = 10

for i in range(step - 1, len(large_list), step):
    within_range.append(any(large_list[i] - 100 <= large_list[i-j] <= large_list[i] + 100 for j in range(1, step)))
```

This will go through every 10th element in the list and add `True` to the `within_range` list if any of the previous 9 elements were within 100 of it and `False` otherwise.

Comment: Oh! That makes more sense. I was going to check to see for each number if it was in the certain range.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting an error with this code. First error with the bracket "]" at the very end. And after removing that bracket and running the code again, I get a SyntaxError "Unexpected EOF while parsing".

Comment: @usernameirrelevant Should work now. The bracket at the end was supposed to be a closing parentheses.